# Local notification not working ionic 2

Tags: android, notifications, ionic2, local

I'm trying to add local notifications but I don't know where is my mistake. There are no errors but when I tested my app on mobile (android), then no notification shown. Here are my steps:

1- Installation

```
ionic plugin add de.appplant.cordova.plugin.local-notification
npm install --save @ionic-native/local-notifications
```

2- app.module.ts

```
import { LocalNotifications } from '@ionic-native/local-notifications';
providers: [..., LocalNotifications]
```

3-

Home.ts

```
import { LocalNotifications } from '@ionic-native/local-notifications';
constructor(..., public localNotifications: LocalNotifications) {}

schedule() {
    let date=  new Date(new Date().getTime() + 5 * 1000);
    alert("Your notification will be shown at " + date);
    this.localNotifications.schedule({
        id: 1,
        title: "Test Title",
        text: "Delayed Notification",
        at: date,
        //sound: null,
        //every: 'week'
    });
 }
```

Home.html

```
<button ion-button full (click)="schedule()">test notification</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem solved by adding the name of local notification plugin to "config.xml"